# SQL query to calculate amount based on time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help to calculate amount based on time range. Also, need to come up with calculation for the whole month. It is a shift transaction calculation based on check-in date.

Eg: 
Shift 01/05/2019 starts at 8:00:00 and ends at 02/05/2019 07:59:59
This is my sql

```
Select CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120) Date, 
SUM(P.Amount - B.TourismTaxAmount) Amount 
From Bookings B 
Inner Join BookingPayments BP On B.ID = BP.BookingID 
Inner Join Payments P On P.ID = BP.PaymentID 
Where BookingStatus IN (2,3,4,6) and 
IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn) >= '2019-05-01 08:00:00' and
IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn) <= '2019-05-02 07:59:59'  
group by CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120) 
order by CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120)
```

The following is the output:

```
-------------------------
| Date         | Amount |
-------------------------
| 2019-05-01   | 123.00 |
| 2019-05-02   | 456.00 |
-------------------------
```

This SQL is already correct.. But how can i make the output as follows:

```
-------------------------
| Date         | Amount |
-------------------------
| 2019-05-01   | 579.00 |
-------------------------
```

And from the above.. i need to generate monthly shift summary by date and output as follows:

```
-------------------------
| Date         | Amount |
-------------------------
| 2019-05-01   | 579.00 |
| 2019-05-02   | 891.00 |
| 2019-05-03   | 721.00 |
| ..........   | .....  |
| ..........   | .....  |
-------------------------
```

Appreciate your help and solutions..
Thanks

Comment: Could You provide some sample data?

Comment: @Julie . . . Based on the syntax, I added a SQL Server tag.

Comment: Your question, as it is presented, suggests (in my view) a more fundamental issue that would make any query very sensitive to errors. There is no element within the shown code/data that could be used as a single entity identification, something like `Shift_ID`. Imagine that you have an error in your data (the cause is irrelevant here) such that you have a check-in, another check-in, and then a check-out. How would your query behave? (of course, this is just a very simple example and you can think of many others, far more complex that this).

Comment: @FDavidov Thanks for your comment. There is shift ID.. but I cannot use it as shift ID is not break by time range 08:00 to the 07:59 the next day. There are 3 shifts and shifts are flexi. Reports for transactions by shifts quite easy to generate because no time frame needed. But this query is to generate report for the finance as the batch cut-off time is 8:00 to 8:00 next day... im really stuck at the moment..

Comment: @Julie, I understand. And yet, my words about the weakness of the solution remain solid from my perspective. In any case, I see that Gordon's post answers your question. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @FDavidov Thanks.. you did help too.. you give me some ideas to think.. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract 8 hours before doing the aggregation.  You can do this most easily be defining a variable (well, column) with the date expression that you want, resulting in:

```
Select convert(char(10), v.dte, 120) as Date, 
       sum(P.Amount - B.TourismTaxAmount) as Amount 
From Bookings B Inner Join
     BookingPayments BP
     On B.ID = BP.BookingID Inner Join
     Payments P
     On P.ID = BP.PaymentID cross apply
     (values (convert(date, dateadd(hour, -8, coalesce(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn))))
     ) v(dte)
Where BookingStatus in (2, 3, 4, 6) and 
      v.dte >= '2019-05-01' and
      v.dte < '2019-05-02'  
group by v.dte 
order by v.dte;
```

This will also readily extend to multiple dates or months.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!.. now i can smile.. hahaha.. thanks a lot.. this works perfectly for me..

Answer (score 1):

use window function sum() with order by date

```
Select CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120) Date, 
SUM(P.Amount - B.TourismTaxAmount) over(order by CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120)) Amount 
From Bookings B 
Inner Join BookingPayments BP On B.ID = BP.BookingID 
Inner Join Payments P On P.ID = BP.PaymentID 
Where BookingStatus IN (2,3,4,6) and 
IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn) >= '2019-05-01 08:00:00' and
IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn) <= '2019-05-02 07:59:59'  

order by CONVERT(char(10), IsNull(CheckInDate, DateCheckIn), 120)
```

Comment: There are 7 transactions in 1/5/2019 from 08:00:00 to 23:5959 and 1 transaction on 2/5/2019 from 00:00:00 to 07:59:59..  It repeat 7 times for 1/5/2019 amount 123.00 and the last line display 2/5/2019 amount 579.00. Almost there but still not correct..

Comment: @Julie could you plz crete your table with data here in https://dbfiddle.uk/ so that i can check with proper data

Comment: here's the sample data : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b997185231f90729d77297f697a05046

Comment: FYI.. CheckInDate is the expected check-in date and DateCheckIn is the real check-in date

Comment: @Julie https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4375bc9efaf6a37ca4cac0c3025a4471  check this link did it solve your probelm

Comment: it is not correct.. the expected result is (1/5/2019 , 72.00) and (2/5/2019, 38.00).  The time range required is 08:00:00 to 07:59:59 next day

Answer (score 0):

For Sql-Server I would first create a SQL, which brings the Date-Column in the right format with

```
Select Year(myDate)*10000+Month(myDate)*100+Day(myDate) as MyNewDate ...
```

Then it's easier to group on it, if you use the query inside an CTE via WITH.

Comment: can help to explain?.. I'm not use to create complex sql.. >.<

Comment: Here is a simple SELECT from a Table Report (my demo datas) to the Column Created (my DateColumn):  

`WITH MyDateSelect(MyDate) AS
  (SELECT 10000*YEAR(r.Created)+100*MONTH(r.Created)+DAY(r.Created) AS MyDate FROM Report r)
SELECT COUNT(*), MyDate FROM MyDateSelect
  GROUP BY MyDate`

Comment: By the way... the Window function from posting below is more powerful. But in my opinion the CTE based solution helps to get a better step by step solution.